# Programmatically unlock iphone with a paired bluetooth device?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I need to make an ios app for iphone with the following behavior.

1. There will be a bluetooth button paired with the iphone.
2. The iphone will be in the locked state in some distance from the button.
3. I click the button and the iphone becomes unlocked and my app transits to foreground.
4. Then other button clicks are handled by my app.
5. After some idle time the iphone becomes locked again (the screen turns off, my app transits to background, etc).
6. Go to step 2.

So, I'm specifically interested if the step 2 is possible at all?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely not possible to programmatically unlock iPhone from your application.

It's question of security.

But you can prevent device from locking if your app in foreground:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES
```

Comment: I see. Can my app always run in foreground even in locked state to receive commands from bluetooth button? Say, I want the iphone take a picture and do some processing when I press the bluetooth button. In the locked state.

Comment: Bluetooth functionality is very limited in background mode, but exact answer will depend of your application tasks, I haven't enough information.  And don't forget that in some cases iOS could terminate your app. You can read more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html

Comment: Also, a lot of things depend on your BT-device. For example, maybe it's possible at first to wake up iPhone and after send data.

Comment: What do you mean by 'wake up'?